# Improving Keras Training Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

I am currently writing a program to predict the severity of a biopsy for Prostate Cancer using Keras. There are 6 different ratings from 0 to 5. Currently the accuracy is stuck at about 16% which is essentially 1/6 and when used, it predicts everything as a score of 1. The training data does have a larger quantity of images that are rated 1, but I duplicated the other sets so all the values would have the same amount of training data.
This is the current model I am using:

```
model = Sequential() 

model.add(Conv2D(4, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32, 32, 1))) 
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have an ordinal response variable, and the usual methods of classification are not quite right. Look into how ordinal logistic regression goes.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- Defining you own CNN is generally not a great idea.

  - I would consider simplifying to just a few convolutional layers followed by a dense layer. Once you've demonstrated that it learns something, you can add layers to improve the accuracy
  - Also consider using an "out of the box" CNN. For small datasets, ResNet-18 is often a good choice to get things started (and it should be easy to find a keras implementation; you'll just have to provide the number of desired classes, etc.).
- You are approaching this as a classification problem. But this seems more like a regression problem. For example, it makes more sense to have a loss like $\mathcal{L} = (\text{predicted - expected})^2$
- It looks like you're applying two softmax functions, which is a mistake (though if you're just taking the argmax, it probably doesn't matter).
- In a larger sense, I would recommend working through one of the MNIST tutorials and then swapping out the dataset (and then switching from classification to regression). Jumping in the deep end with a new task on a new dataset will lead to lots of spinning your wheels.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use transfer learning if you want a good result with your CNN model.
You can use pre-trained **ResNet-18** model and add a few dense layer with **softmax** activation at the output layer.
It is not recommended to use **softmax** function in other than output layer, you should use **relu or leaky relu** instead.